# Approximations to the Mertens function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The Mertens function $M(x)$ is the summatory Möbius function i.e.

$$M(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{x} \mu (k)$$

The conjecture that $M(x) = \mathcal{O}\left(x^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon}\right)$ was shown to  be equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis but a stronger version of the same was disproved by Odlyzko and te Reile in 1985. Are there any known bounds on or approximations to the Mertens function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best known bound under the Riemann Hypothesis is due to Soundararajan, see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0723). This paper and its MathSciNet review (MR2542220) contain further information about what is known unconditionally and what is expected to be the precise order of magnitude.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This is discussed at considerable length in the very nice paper by [Kotnik and van de Lune (in Experimental Mathematics).](http://www.emis.de/journals/EM/expmath/volumes/13/13.4/Kotnik.pdf)